# How to create a video player app that supports formats which are not natively supported by the windows 10 mobile platform?

Tags: uwp, windows-10-mobile

So I want to create a video player app that can play multiple formats of video which are not natively supported by the windows 10 mobile platform like flv, ogg, mov, vob etc. So I dont have any idea like how to start on this. I have seen a app in windows store which can play flv format but flv only. So it means it is possible to create app that can play formats which are not natively supported by the platform. So I need some direction on how to start on building such an app. Where to start? I think it has something to do with the codecs of each format but how do I implement those codecs in a UWP app?

Comment: Check out JPlayer you don't need to invent the wheel. http://jplayer.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, there are apps on windows store like vlc that can play several format that windows doesn't support natively. For that you can use FFmpegInterop that is open-source wrapper around FFmpeg for windows runtime. Then you'll be able to play any type of media that FFmpeg support (That is huge actually). FFmpegInterop is a Windows Runtime Component that produce a MediaStreamSource. You can assign this as media source to your MediaElement. For a complete guide visit [Using FFmpeg in Windows Applications](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/06/05/using-ffmpeg-in-windows-applications/#34eQhb52FWI2hFJO.97).

[FFmpegInterop library for Windows](https://github.com/Microsoft/FFmpegInterop)

[Compile and Use FFmpeg Libraries for Windows Runtime](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/WinRT)

Comment: Thanks will look into it and will try to include that source into the project and fiddle with it. That was a cool library. If you know or familiar with any other such library please let me know I will look into it as well.